# VBScript Using Out of Date ProgID for MediaPlayer

Tags: vbscript, windows-media-player

I am needing to update a VBScript that runs on a wide variety of machines and plays a sound file in the background. Here is my existing code:

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Sound.URL = "C:\Windows\Media\Alarm01.wav"
Sound.Controls.play
do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
wscript.sleep 100
loop
wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
```

When I run this code, I have recently begun getting the following error on many, but not all machines:

```
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'WMPlayer.OCX.7'
Code: 800A01AD
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

I understand that this is because this object is deprecated. How is one supposed to do this these days?

I have tried running the program using the 32 bit version of cscript and wscript, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you playing a WAV file or a compressed format such as MP3 or AAC? If the latter, you could use Audacity to convert it to a WAV file. That will open up more playback options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script still works on the latest Windows 11 builds, so the problem machines are configured differently than default. Maybe WMP has been uninstalled or disabled. Also check policies and AV software settings.

You may be able to get it working by re-registering wmp.dll:

`regsvr32 wmp.dll`

Otherwise, you may need to explore alternate solutions. Below are some options.

**Option 1: PlayAudio.hta**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<hta:application
  showintaskbar=no
>
<script language=VBScript>
Window.ResizeTo 0,0
Window.MoveTo 999999999,999999999
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio src="Test.mp3" autoplay>
</body>
</html>
```

If you can use a WAV file, you can compile a simple C# program like this:

**Option 2: PlayAudio.cs**

```
using System.Media;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("Test.wav");
        player.PlaySync();
    }
}
```

Also for a WAV file, you can use PowerShell like this:

**Option 3: PlayAudio.ps1**

```
(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "test.wav").PlaySync()
```

You can use [RunHidden](https://lesferch.github.io/RunHidden/) to run the PS1 script hidden.

**Option 4: PlayAudio.vbs**

Play WAV file via PowerShell launched from VBScript

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
SoundFile = "test.wav"
Command = "(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer '" & SoundFile & "').PlaySync()"
CmdLine = "Powershell.exe -Command " & Command
oWSH.Run CmdLine,0,False
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will give these a go. The Powershell solution might work best of all for my application, but I will let you know.

Comment: @samcosmo You didn't say what type of audio file you're playing.

Comment: Apologies. I am using wav files. I have updated the original questio to reflect this. Powershell worked a treat.

Comment: @samcosmo Good to hear. Are you using the PS1 with RunHidden or the PowerShell code via VBS?